# Pivot some part of table in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, pivot, oracle12c

I have two tables they are more complex so for simplicity I created simpler versions but I get similar output as you can see in my sql join. each supplier has as many rows as many surcharge codes the item has.thr item can have no surcharge or 1-n. for simplicity I created just 3 codes byt in the surcharge table there are more than 50 codes and I dont know how many of them for an item will be in the output table, I see it after join when I see repeated rows for supplier with the same item and turnover.

```
create table supplier (
supplier_ID number,
supplier_name varchar2(20),
item varchar2(12),
turnover number,
surcharge_id number
);

create table surcharge (
surcharge_ID number,
surcharge_code number,
basic_value number,
surcharge_name varchar2(12),
weight number
);

insert into supplier values ( 1 , 'ABC_company' , 'A' , 1000, 1 );
insert into supplier values ( 1 , 'ABC_company' , 'A' , 1000, 2 );
insert into supplier values ( 1 , 'XYZ_company' , 'X' , 50, 1 );
insert into supplier values ( 1 , 'XYZ_company' , 'X' , 50, 2 );
insert into supplier values ( 1 , 'XYZ_company' , 'X' , 50, 3 );
insert into supplier values ( 1 , 'KLM_company' , 'K' , 280, null );

insert into surcharge values ( 1 , 20 , 0.5 , 'gold', 0.112 );
insert into surcharge values ( 2 , 50 , 0.3 , 'silver', 0.080 );
insert into surcharge values ( 3 , 80 , 0.1 , 'bronze', 0.010 );


select supplier_name,item,turnover,surcharge_code,basic_value,surcharge_name,weight 
from supplier 
left join surcharge on supplier.surcharge_id=surcharge.surcharge_ID
order by supplier_name,item;

SUPPLIER_NAME   ITEM    TURNOVER    SURCHARGE_CODE  BASIC_VALUE SURCHARGE_NAME     WEIGHT
ABC_company       A       1000         20                 .5            gold        .112
ABC_company       A       1000         50                 .3            silver      .08
KLM_company       K       280          -                  -              -           - 
XYZ_company       X       50           50                 .3            silver      .08
XYZ_company       X       50           80                 .1            bronze      .01
XYZ_company       X       50           20                 .5            gold        .112
```

it is possible to pivot such table to this desired output?bear in mind, you dont know what code and how many of them if any will be joined.

desired output

```
SUPPLIER_NAME   ITEM    TURNOVER       20      50     80    gold        silver     bronze 
 ABC_company      A       1000         .5      .3     -     .112        .08        -
 KLM_company      K       280          -       -      -     -           -          -
 XYZ_company      X       50           .5      .3     .1    .112        .08        .01
```

Comment: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/202153)

Comment: If you want to pivot the rows then you need to know what values there will be beforehand. If you want a dynamic pivot then you are better doing it in whatever client programming language you are using to access the database.

Comment: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b96cdc1a04178fa24cf4bb162d932349) is a non-dynamic pivot of your data.